# Playwright webkit can't run WebAssembly

Tags: webkit, webassembly, playwright

I'm trying to run a webpage that calls a `.wasm` file in playwright webkit

```js
const { webkit } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
    const browser = await webkit.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.on("pageerror", err => {
        console.error(err.message)
    })
    await page.goto('https://wasmbyexample.dev/examples/hello-world/demo/rust/');
})();
```

However, I get the following page-error:

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WebAssembly`

Seems that the `WebAssembly` object within the browser is not even initialized.

Any idea why this is happening?

If it matters, I'm on windows.

Comment: Quick answer. It seems that they know about this issue https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/54f07f9bd6ede736570e168976f1eee6bf8c9e2d/test/capabilities.spec.js#L20

Comment: Playwright WebKit on Windows does not support WebAssembly at this stage. Can you use WSL or Docker to run a Linux build of WebKit?